# Give an example of an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ which is maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

My answer right now is just $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ resulting in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ as $(1,1)$. But this is the entire ring... Help?

Comment: Hint: think of primes as a general case.

Comment: The ideal generated by $(0,1)$ is not maximal. If $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $I$ is maximal if and only if $R/I$ is a field. $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/\langle(0,1)\rangle \cong \mathbb Z$ is not a field.

Comment: By the way, it is important to be precise. $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are not ideals, they are elements of the ring which determine principle ideals.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think the OP meant the ideal generated by $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, not each individually.

Comment: Perhaps, but again, if that was his intent, the impreciseness of his statement makes it all the more problematic. My reading gives at least two prime ideals, but your reading doesn't give a maximal ideal, but rather then entire ring... @Hayden

Comment: Precisely; the OP mentions that this results in the entire ring, so he may not realize that the ring itself is not a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if your ideal is maximal, let $R$ be a ring and let $M$ be your maximal ideal. If ${R}/{M}$ is a field, then $M$ is maximal.

I gave you a hint to think of primes as a general case. For example $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{2Z}$ is an example of a maximal ideal in your case.